Efficiently Removing an Integer from a Matrix of Row-Wise Permutations of Integers
I have an n x n matrix where each row is a permutation of the integers from 1 to n.
For a given integer k in {1,2,...,n}, my goal is to locate k in each row and remove it, such that the remaining elements in each row stay in their original order.
For concreteness, suppose X is that matrix and n = 5.
import numpy as np
X= np.array([
    [4, 3, 5, 1, 2],
    [5, 3, 2, 1, 4],
    [3, 2, 4, 1, 5],
    [2, 4, 3, 5, 1],
    [3, 5, 2, 1, 4]
])

For k = 1, I want the output to be:
X = np.array([
    [4, 3, 5, 2],
    [5, 3, 2, 4],
    [3, 2, 4, 5],
    [2, 4, 3, 5],
    [3, 5, 2, 4]
])

Is there a way to remove k that scales well with m?
Currently i create a mask that identifies entries in each row of X that are not equal to k. This way, mask[i] gives me a Boolean array that is True for elements in row i that aren't equal to k.
Next, I apply the mask to each row: I iterate over each row and use X[i][mask[i]] to filter out the value k in each row. The result for each row is then assigned to the corresponding row in Xnew.
m = 5
n = m
X = np.array([np.random.permutation(np.arange(1, n + 1)) for _ in range(m)])
k = 1
mask = X != k
Xnew = np.zeros([n,m-1])
for i in range(m):
    Xnew[i]=X[i][mask[i]]
    

This approach works for small matrices but may not scale well with larger matrices due to the loop over each row. I'm wondering if there's a more efficient way to accomplish this?

How large is n?

How many times will you have to do this?

@nocomment n < 10e5.

@jared this is part of an iterative algorithm that removes 1 integer from the set of n integers at each timestep. number of timesteps is pre-determined or determined by a stopping criteria.

Since you have permutations, you are sure that the same number of items will be filtered out per row. Therefore, you can safely apply the mask vectorially and reshape the 1D intermediate to the original number of rows:
mask = X != k

X[mask].reshape(X.shape[0], -1)

Output:
array([[4, 3, 5, 2],
       [5, 3, 2, 4],
       [3, 2, 4, 5],
       [2, 4, 3, 5],
       [3, 5, 2, 4]])

Timing on 1M rows:
103 ms ± 8.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

Note that the way you generate the random permutations will be the bottleneck. You could also consider generating directly the permutations without the value, which should give similar results.

If mozway's solution has good enough performance for you, keep it as it is short and clean.
If this is your bottleneck, you can speed it up (for larger m and n about 1.5-2x faster) by using numba and instead of using mask write the result while reading values from X:
import line_profiler
import numpy as np
import numba as nb


def mozway(X, k):
    mask = X != k
    return X[mask].reshape(X.shape[0], -1)

@nb.njit('int64[:](int64[:], int64, int64)', nopython=True)
def omit_some_value(X, output_size, k):
    result = np.empty(output_size, dtype=np.int64)
    idx = 0
    for value in X:
        if value != k:
            result[idx] = value
            idx += 1
    return result


def main():
    m = 10_000
    n = 10_000
    X = np.array([np.random.permutation(np.arange(1, n + 1)) for _ in range(m)])
    k = 1
    mask = X != k
    Xnew = np.zeros([n, m - 1])
    for i in range(m):
        Xnew[i] = X[i][mask[i]]

    for _ in range(10):
        Xnew2 = mozway(X, k)
        Xnew3 = omit_some_value(X.reshape(-1), X.shape[0] * (X.shape[1] - 1), k).reshape(X.shape[0],-1)
    assert np.allclose(Xnew, Xnew2)
    assert np.allclose(Xnew, Xnew3)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    profiler = line_profiler.LineProfiler()
    profiler.add_function(main)
    profiler.enable_by_count()
    main()
    profiler.print_stats()


You can use this setup to benchmark on your computer and with your m and n values
Sidenote: for some reason I had to do reshaping outside numba, there was some strange error about non contiguous array, which should be contiguous..
